# rowspan for 3 columns using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table

I have a category list that contains name and subject list.
The subject list contains name and course list. 
The course list contain name.

I want to display this data in table that will rowspan category or subject if they are the same. For example:

```
Category  Subject  Course
cat1      sub1     ''
          sub2     cour1
                   cour2
          sub3     ''
cat3      ''
```

Currently I have it working for two columns using this:

```
 <table  class="curvetable5" style="width:99%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="30%">Category</th>
        <th width="30%">Subject</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody  ng-repeat="category in organization">    
       <td rowspan="{{category.subjectList.length+1}}">{{category.categoryName}}</td>    
       <tr  ng-repeat="subject in category.subjectList">         
            <td>{{ subject.name }}</td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

However, I am having trouble doing it for 3 columns. This is the code I have that is not working. The course name are not being displayed and subject name become listed in column order instead of row order. Any suggestion:

```
<table  class="curvetable5" style="width:99%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="30%">Category</th>
        <th width="30%">Subject</th>
        <th width="40%">Course</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody  ng-repeat="category in organization">    
       <td rowspan="{{category.subjectList.length+1}}">{{category.categoryName}}</td>    
       <tr  ng-repeat="subject in category.subjectList">         
            <td rowspan="{{subject.courseList.length+1}}">{{ subject.name }}</td>
            <tr  ng-repeat="course in subject.courseList">       
                <td>{{ course.name }}</td>
            </tr> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Sample Data:

```
[
 {"id":95,"categoryName":"A new catagory",
        "subjectList":[{"id":112,"subjectname":"2ndnewcat","curcount":0,
                "courseList":"[{\"name\":\"-\",\"curcount\":0}]"},
        {"id":76,"subjectname":"ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ_class","curcount":0,
                "courseList":[{"coursename":"thiswillbenew111111111112","curcount":1}]}]},
 {"id":93,"categoryName":"David Test",
        "subjectList":[{"id":75,"subjectname":"This is a test","curcount":1,
                "courseList":[{"coursename":"newewst1","curcount":0}]}]},
 {"id":116,"categoryName":"New Category",
        "subjectList":[{"id":79,"subjectname":"New Subject","curcount":2,
                "courseList":[{"coursename":"ISO training part 2","curcount":0}]}]},
 {"id":0,"categoryName":"cat1",
        "subjectList":[{"id":15,"subjectname":"test","curcount":4,
                "courseList":"[{\"name\":\"-\",\"curcount\":0}]"}]},
 {"id":11,"categoryName":"cat2",
        "subjectList":[{"id":68,"subjectname":"asdasd","curcount":5,
                "courseList":[{"coursename":"david1","curcount":0},{"coursename":"thisisatest","curcount":0}]}]},
 {"id":12,"categoryName":"cate3",
        "subjectList":[{"id":12,"subjectname":"newest1","curcount":6,
                "courseList":[{"coursename":"cous1","curcount":0}]}]},
 {"id":163,"categoryName":"emptylist",
        "subjectList":"[{\"name\":\"-\",\"curcount\":0}]"}
 ]
```

This is current code I am testing. It will will rowspan the category, display each subject once and then display all the courses for each subject in list in a single cell. I would prefer to rowspan subject too, but this is what I got working so far.

```
<table  class="curvetable5" style="width:99%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="30%">Category</th>
            <th width="30%">Subject</th>
            <th width="40%">Course</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody  ng-repeat="category in organization">
        <td rowspan="{{category.subjectList.length+1}}">{{category.categoryName}}</td>
        <tr  ng-repeat="subject in category.subjectList">        
            <td>{{ subject.subjectname }}</td>
            <td> <li ng-repeat="course in subject.courseList" >{{ course.coursename }} </li></td>
        </tr>
        <td ng-if="category.subjectList.length==27">&nbsp;</td>
        <td ng-if="category.subjectList.length==27">&nbsp;</td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks,
AB

Comment: Please define "not working". What does that mean? How is it not working?

Comment: I added the issue I am having.

Comment: Please include a sample of the data structure that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The two column case should be:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="dept in org.deptList">
    <tr ng-repeat="subj in dept.subjList">
       <td rowspan="dept.subjList.length+1">
          {{dept.name}}
       </td>
       <td>
           {{subj.name}}
       </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

For the three column case, nest a `<table>` in the `<td>` element:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="dept in org.deptList">
    <tr ng-repeat="subj in dept.subjList">
       <td rowspan="dept.subjList.length+1">
          {{dept.name}}
       </td>
       <td>
          <table>
             <tr ng-repeat="class in subj.classList">
                 <td rowspan="subj.classList.length+1">
                    {{subj.name}}
                 </td>
                 <td>
                    {{class.name}}
                 </td>
             </tr>
          </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. However, this is not working for me. When I tried your three columns model, the third column is empty and 2nd column cell each contain a smaller table inside that has both subject and course.

Comment: Please include a sample of the data structure that you are using.

Comment: I added sample data